# Issue saving decimal value in mysql db using cakephp save

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0

I have a form and while submitting I am passing values to the controller and array looks something like this.

```
    [submit] => Post
    [File] => Array
        (
            [content] => dfgdfgdfg
        )

    [Groups] => Array
        (
            [group_name] => 190
        )

    [News] => Array
        (
            [is_private] => 1
            [user_id] => 285
            [content] => <p>dfgdfgdfg</p>

        )

    [Posts] => Array
        (
            [rating] => 5.2
            [rating_enabled] => on
        )
```

All the values except the rating is saved correctly into the db. I am using a slider in the front-end and its value is rating.
In db the rating field is decimal type and the type of Posts[rating] is string so I converted it to float using floatval.

```
if(  isset($this->request->data['Posts']['rating_enabled'])  ){
                 $this->request->data['News']['rating'] = floatval($this->request->data['Posts']['rating']);
            }
```

After that saving is done

```
$this->News->save($this->request->data);
```

Only $this->request->data['News']['rating'] is not saved but when checked the data array the value of is

```
 [News] => Array
        (
            [is_private] => 1
            [user_id] => 285
            [content] => <p>dfgdfgdfg</p>
            [rating] => 5.2
        )
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong

Comment: What is the data type you have used in MySQL?

Comment: I have tried with types decimal and float but I was not getting the value inserted

Comment: Specifically how have you defined the decimal? You need to add under the values field `5,2` for example in order to support 5 digits with 2 decimal places (ie ###.##)

Comment: Have you `$ cake bake model all` ? Cake does not save fields that are not in model if my memory is good at this point

Comment: Please post your insert query here

Comment: is `rating_enabled` saved?. Can you please enable debug mode and post the insert query/queries that cake generates?

Comment: It was my mistake I forgot clear the model cache

Answer (score 0):

Please check mysql table rating must be float

Comment: I had changed the decimal to float also and tried but the result is the same